# Keycloak option Sync LDAP roles/groups to Keycloak missing

Tags: keycloak

I have successfully configured Active Directory as a user federation LDAP provider in Keycloak.
Users get synced and authentication is working with basic username + password.
I have configured ldap-group-mapper to `READ_ONLY` mode and `LOAD_GROUPS_BY_MEMBER_ATTRIBUTE` but no groups ever get added to Keycloak. I have no error in the server log.
Screenshot of the group mapper config.
[image]

In some tutorials I found there is a button for syncing roles/groups when setting up the mapper but this is not available in the latest version as it seems, can it be triggered manually in some other way? Searching for users and or groups does not seem to trigger the groups to appear in Keycloak.

Comment: Pretty weird, I also could not find, I would have to look at the release notes of the new version to see if it was deleted on purpose

Comment: In the new version, when I Sync All Users on User federation configuration, by default it also imports all the groups.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After searching for a long time, I found the action button in the top right corner (see Screenshot), which lets you synchronize users.
Hope this helps!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WxrV.png)

Comment: Yes, but after the first sync, the groups the user belongs to are not synced any more.

Answer (score 0):

The feature has been removed from the REST API with Keycloak 19.

If you compare the API documentation

- Keycloak 18: https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/18.0/rest-api/ you will find "Trigger sync of mapper data related to ldap mapper".
- Keycloak 19: https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.1/rest-api/ there is not much to find for "user-storage" which was an essential part of the request path.